# Auto backup database before retention policy kicks in

Tags: influxdb

I have a database with RP of 7 days. I am trying to figure out how can I automatically backup the database before the RP comes into play. So far what I think might work is to run a cron job to backup the database every 6 days and 20 hours. Is there a better way?